# Can I limit a CSS animation to play only once when toggling a class on the same element defining a different animation?

Tags: angularjs, css, css-animations, ng-animate

Basically I'm trying to show an animation on certain elements that were affected in a "most recent action". After this animation completes it shouldn't play again. The problem I have at the moment is that I also define an animation which runs when the element(s) are "selected". When the element is deselected the original animation plays again, even if the `animation-iteration-count` of 1 has been reached. I could certainly set up an event listener for when `animationend` fires and then remove the class associated with the animation. I'm more trying to reason about why this doesn't work as intended. I guess this is sort of the opposite of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737736/css-keyframe-animations-only-running-once-in-angular-app).

```js
document.querySelector('.one-time-animation').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
 e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
})
```

```css
.one-time-animation {
    animation: one-time-animation 2s forwards 1;
}

.selected {
    animation: selected 2s forwards 1;
}

@keyframes one-time-animation {
    from {
        background:red;
    }
    to {
        background:transparent;
    }
}

@keyframes selected {
    from {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 green inset;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px green inset;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="one-time-animation">Click to toggle selected class</div>
```

Comment: So, basically the answer seems to be yes, if you chain the original animation on to the selector targeting the class you're toggling. Otherwise, use transition, instead of animation if possible. Otherwise just JS the damn thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure CSS Solution:** (without polluting the `selected` style)

Assuming the animation provided in question is the exact same used in your application and not just some random sample, you could actually replace it with a `transition` instead of an `animation`.  This would also make sure that the original animation is never removed and hence never replayed.

```js
document.querySelector('.one-time-animation').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
})
```

```css
.one-time-animation {
  animation: one-time-animation 2s forwards 1;
}
@keyframes one-time-animation {
  from {
    background: red;
  }
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

/* do the following changes */

.selected {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px green inset;
  transition: box-shadow 2s ease;
}

/* the below is generally not required but if the box-shadow just appears instantly instead of gradually then uncomment it
div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 green inset;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-time-animation">Click to toggle selected class</div>
```

---

**Reason:**

The animations are working as they are supposed to be based on the specifications. On click, when the `selected` class is added to the element, it no longer has `one-time-animation`. This is because the latest specified value for the `animation` property over-rides the previous specified one (as rightly pointed out by shennan).

When the `selected` class is toggled off, the `one-time-animation` becomes applicable and by now the user-agent has no remembrance of this animation having been present on the element earlier. This results in the animation getting re-executed even though the `animation-iteration-count` is set to 1.

One way to fix this issue would be to let the user agent know that the original animation is never really removed from the element. This can be performed by retaining it as part of the stack in the `selected` class. Animation property can support multiple animations in a comma separated format. The original animation doesn't run again because the user agent now treats it as ever present and thus maintains the iteration counter.

```js
document.querySelector('.one-time-animation').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
})
```

```css
.one-time-animation {
  animation: one-time-animation 2s forwards 1;
}
.selected {
  animation: one-time-animation 2s forwards 1, selected 2s forwards 1;
}
@keyframes one-time-animation {
  from {
    background: red;
  }
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@keyframes selected {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 green inset;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px green inset;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-time-animation">Click to toggle selected class</div>
```

If it is not possible to add the original animation as part of the stack for `selected` class (say because it is used for multiple elements each of which have different original animations) then the approach should be to get the current `animation`, append the `selected` animation to it and then set it via JS.

I am not a JS expert but the below snippet should give you an idea of what I mean.

```js
var i = false;

document.querySelector('.one-time-animation').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(e.target);
  var currAnim = style.getPropertyValue(PrefixFree.prefix + 'animation-name') + ' ' + style.getPropertyValue(PrefixFree.prefix + 'animation-duration') + ' ' + style.getPropertyValue(PrefixFree.prefix + 'animation-fill-mode') + ' ' + style.getPropertyValue(PrefixFree.prefix + 'animation-iteration-count');
  var newAnim;
  if (!i)
    newAnim = currAnim + ', selected 2s forwards 1;';
  else
    newAnim = currAnim.substring(0, currAnim.indexOf(','));
  e.target.setAttribute('style', PrefixFree.prefix + 'animation: ' + newAnim);
  i = !i;
});
```

```css
.one-time-animation {
  animation: one-time-animation 2s forwards 1;
}
@keyframes one-time-animation {
  from {
    background: red;
  }
  to {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@keyframes selected {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 green inset;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px green inset;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-time-animation">Click to toggle selected class</div>
```

Comment: I like your CSS solution, but your JavaScript one is a little overkill for what it's doing. It also won't work on non-webkit browsers (Firefox is still pretty popular). I would remove it and stick to your much more elegant CSS solution.

Comment: @shennan: I already updated the JS solution to support Firefox :) The JS solution is more of a proof of concept thing. It was added because there can be cases where the original animation is different but the selected animation is common (as I mentioned in answer).

Comment: Yes, you've just added another bulk of inelegant code to deal with other browsers. I'm not trying to be contrary; I just think your answer would be much better without the JS solution. I've already provided a JS solution that uses an extra *one* line of code in order to make it work. You've added 20+ lines. Just a suggestion; I don't want to cause offence. :-)

Comment: I've given you the reason. But you're well within your right not to agree with it. P.S, you might want to keep trying on the Firefox support; your solution still doesn't work on Firefox (testing with version 40+). It also doesn't appear to work on Safari either. Your CSS solution works perfectly on both though. :-)

Comment: No problem. It's true that the `classList` is not supported by older browsers, but the OP also used this, so I felt this was a separate issue that he would likely know of already.

Comment: @shennan: No, I wasn't mentioning about the use of `classList` but more about cases where the class has other properties and so cannot be removed completely. In such cases the only option would be to manipulate the animation stack :(

Comment: Well we're only dealing with the information that the OP has given us. Your hypothetical situation doesn't exist in his current example, and is easily rectified even if it did.

Comment: I'm impressed by this CSS solution, but I must admit it seems difficult to reason about. You add a class "selected" which specifies 2 animations, but the browser has remembrance of running previously because of a different class on the element?!? and yet when I remove a class with nothing to do with the original animation it has no remembrance of a property value which hasn't really changed... I get it, but I don't really get it. Polluting a second style declaration with information about a different one may pose problems, as you noted prior to your JS approach. Nice work.

Comment: @bodine: It has no remembrance because the original animation **does not** exist on the element once the selected class is added. The selected class specifies a value which **overwrites** the prior defined one. In the CSS solution I added, the selected class does not remove the original but just adds one more and hence browser retains state of original animation.

Comment: I understand why you wouldn't want to pollute the second style but that is the only pure CSS way possible and it also affirms my reasoning that the animation must still exist on the element for the browser to retain its state. I knew you were looking more for a reason than a solution but the reason is the one that I provided and the solution is to back it. The problem was you are thinking the property value doesn't change while actually it **does change**. As I mentioned earlier the value provided in selected class overwrites the one provided before because in CSS the latest declaration wins.

Comment: @bodine: I have also added a different pure CSS solution to my answer (one that does not pollute the other style). Depending on your actual requirement, this might be more suited and efficient.

Comment: @Harry I guess I just really don't like how the browsers handle this, it seems unintuitive. However, this answer is clearly more complete and offers more than one pure CSS solution, as well as a sufficiently understandable explanation. This was, as you mentioned, my intention in asking the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `animation-iteration-count` is reset when it is re-applied due to your toggling the `select` class. This is due to the cascading nature of CSS.

One option would be to simply remove the `one-time-animation` class when you go to select it:

```js
document.querySelector('.selectable').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('one-time-animation');
    e.target.classList.toggle('selected');
})
```

```css
.one-time-animation {
    animation: one-time-animation 2s forwards 1;
}

.selected {
    animation: selected 2s forwards 1;
}

@keyframes one-time-animation {
    from {
        background:red;
    }
    to {
        background:transparent;
    }
}

@keyframes selected {
    from {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 green inset;
    }
    to {
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px green inset;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="selectable one-time-animation">Click to toggle selected class</div>
```

Comment: This is essentially the approach I ended up taking. It came to make sense in my use case because once the user "selects" something the one-time-animation state isn't really valid anymore for the element. But I really don't like polluting the logic of my VM's select method with logic about removing a mostly unrelated class. Alas, this seemed like the lesser of two evils. In my case this animation applies via ngClass if a certain vm property is true, so I simply toggle that state upon ngClick.

Comment: @bodine A pure and elegant CSS solution would have been nice, but over the years I've come to terms with nuances like this. One of my first big lessons in development was learning to separate logic and style. My next big lesson was realising that they can't always be separated. You need to use the tools you have to get the job done.