# Prevent animation from happening second time with CSS-only

Tags: css, media-queries

This might not be possible using CSS-only, but here goes:

Given this bit of CSS:

```
.animated {
    animation:enter-animation 0.5s ease-in-out 3s;
}
@media (max-width:450px) {
    .animated {
        animation:none;
    }
}
```

This triggers an animation on elements with `.animated` class which is visible after the `3s` delay specified above.
If the screen is `450px` or lower, the animation is cancelled.

The behavior I want to change is this: animation triggers (browser window is large enough), then browser window is shrinked below `450px`, then enlarged over `450px` which triggers the animation to run.

I would like to know if there is a CSS-only solution to prevent the animation from running when the browser window grows from under `450px` to over that.

Comment: This seems sort of similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832833/can-i-limit-a-css-animation-to-play-only-once-when-toggling-a-class-on-the-same/32836521#32836521) (not a duplicate though) and as far as I know this is not possible with just CSS. Even though iteration count could be set as 1, once the animation is removed (by the `none`) when it gets reapplied, UA will trigger it again.

Comment: No there is not, are You trying to prevent animation on switching from `landscape` to `portrait` mode on smartphone? If so there is media queries for that.

Comment: Try to set the animation time to 0 for small screens, this will be complicated to implement, there is so many factors.
I will try to do a fiddle later though.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the comments.
@Harry: Perhaps I misunderstand the linked answer, but I think it's a different matter.

Comment: @Bogdan: That could be one use case, currently I'm just trying to prevent it from reoccuring after resizing the browser. But you make a good point.

Comment: @Francisc: The question is different but the crux is the same. Once you remove the animation using `none` and then reapply it, the browser would have no idea that it had executed once already. So, when you shrink the window and then enlarge it again, the browser would re-run the animation.

Comment: @Damiano: Setting animation time to 0 would still trigger it and make it complete instantly though right? I want there to be no animation at all.

Comment: @Harry: I understand now, fair point.